# Aggregating all numeric variables of a list of data frames by all character variables except one

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of data frames/tibbles like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

l <- list(capacity = tribble(~plant, ~month, ~max_capacity, ~min_capacity,
                             "A", "202001", 3000.0, 5000.0,
                             "A", "202002", 2000.0, 4500.0,
                             "B", "202001", 5000.0, 8000.0),
          demand = tribble(~region, ~month, ~demand,
                           "1", "202001", 234.3,
                           "1", "202002", 159.9,
                           "2", "202001", 488))
```

How can I summarise all data frames that all numeric variables are summed by all character variables except "month"?

```
# want, but not in a dynamic way
l$capacity %>%
  group_by(plant) %>% # group by all character variables except "month"
  summarise(max_capacity = sum(max_capacity), min_capacity = sum(min_capacity)) %>%
    # summarise all numeric variables
  ungroup()

l$demand %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(demand = sum(demand)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find the columns to group using `Filter` and `setdiff`, pass this to `group_by_at` which accepts string arguments and use `summarise_if` to sum numeric columns.

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map(l, ~{
   cols <- setdiff(names(Filter(is.character, .x)), 'month')
   .x %>% group_by_at(cols) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)
})

#$capacity
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  plant max_capacity min_capacity
#  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 A             5000         9500
#2 B             5000         8000

#$demand
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  region demand
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 1        394.
#2 2        488
```

Note that `summarise_if` is soon going to be replaced with `across` in newer version of `dplyr`.